# Android Carregar JSON

Tags: android, mysql, json, retrofit

Estou precisando pegar as informações de um JSON, criei um código em php que transforma o banco de dados em mySQL em JSON https://portfoliounopar.000webhostapp.com/index.php, agora preciso pegar essas informações e colocar em um RecyclerView no android, tentei alguns formas, mas sem sucesso até agora, se alguém tiver alguma dica para isso, uma forma simples, tenho que usar Retrofit? Volley? . Obrigadoo.

Answer (score 1):

O google sugere volley, até onde me lembro. 
Para uma aplicação bem simples, você pode simplesmente utilizar:

```
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;


public class HttpRequestHelper {
    public static String getRawResult(String url) {
        HttpURLConnection c = null;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
            c.setUseCaches(false);
            c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            c.setConnectTimeout(40000);
            c.setReadTimeout(40000);
            c.connect();
            int status = c.getResponseCode();

            switch (status) {
                case 200:
                case 201:
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line+"\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    return sb.toString();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Log.i("suaTag", "HttpConnectionHelper error: " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.i("suaTag", "HttpConnectionHelper error: " + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                try {
                    c.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i("suaTag", "HttpConnectionHelper error: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```